# How do I determine the difference between the domain name and resource of a URL?

Tags: c++, web, http-headers

I am writing code that needs to respond to html redirections using the Location header. Mostly it works find, however, in some cases the header simply says to redirect to some resource, presumably on the same host, for example

```
Location: main.html
```

In other cases it will simply provide a new domain, for example

```
Location: abc.example.com
```

Now, how can I tell whether the redirection needs the existing host domain prefixed to the given partial URL without having to check all possible top-level domains in the suffix of the string? The only thing I can think to do is simply try one resultant URL and, if it fails, attempt the other one.

Has anyone got a clever solution or come across this problem before?

Comment: What is sending you those Location headers?  Neither seem like valid absolute or relative URLs (should either start with a protocol or a slash).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I suspected I was getting dodgy responses. It is also possible that I am preprocessing away part of the response, which I will look into. Failing that, I will ignore the invalid responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to section 14.30 of [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) the `Location:` header must specify an *absoluteURI*. RFC 2616 borrows (see section 3.2.1) the specification of the *absoluteURI* from [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), and section 3 of RFC 2396 makes it clear that an *absoluteURI* is, well, an absolute URI.

Any other kind of an URI like the sample responses you're getting, violates RFC 2616. Those responses are invalid, and there is no valid interpretation of them.

Answer (score 0):

First, it does not appear that you're getting valid Location headers.  Location headers must include either absolute URLs (that start with a specifier (e.g. "http:") or relative URLs (that start with either "//hostname" or "/" (for paths).  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2).

That being said, if you're stuck with a server sending you broken Location headers, you could do some heuristics to try to guess whether it starts with a hostname or not.  Obvious ones include whether it ends with common file format extensions (e.g. .html, .txt, .pdf) or common TLD suffixes (e.g. .com, .org, .net).  This isn't fool-proof, as with the explosion of TLDs, there's likely to be overlap with file extensions, and in theory, a file can end in anything (as, for instance, some end with .com).  But it would probably get you 98% of the way there - and then you could just try both and see which gives you an answer.

There's always the possibility that both give you an answer, in which case it's just a Hard Problem(tm).  That's why the specification is what it is - to avoid this kind of ambiguity.